# How to remove scrolling of textview?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a TextView and I am referencing it as "message" in Java and has set it to scrollable like this:

```
 message.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

I have another button called "stop" that would take away the scrolling focus from the message textview. How can I remove the focus and stop scroll?

Comment: You want to stop the scrolling and give the focus to the button?

Comment: no I want to stop the scrolling in the button. button already gets focus

Answer (score 2):

From the [`TextView.setMovementMethod(MovementMethod)`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMovementMethod%28android.text.method.MovementMethod%29) docs:

> Sets the movement method (arrow key handler) to be used for this TextView. This **can be `null` to disallow using the arrow keys** to
>   move the cursor or scroll the view.
>
> Be warned that **if you want a TextView with a key listener or movement
>   method not to be focusable**, or if you want a TextView without a key
>   listener or movement method to be focusable, **you must call
>   `setFocusable(boolean)` again after calling this** to get the focusability
>   back the way you want it.

So this should remove the focus:

```
message.setFocusable(false);
```

while this will take the scrolling away completely:

```
message.setMovementMethod(null);
```